# ReactJS Fetch POST file to Flask Backend (Won't send the data)

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I already read a lot of documentation about fetch and ReactJS and i simply can't found the problem of my code, the situation is that i can select and store the desired file in the state but when i send the submit, Flask does not receive the file, just this message:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2020 18:50:44] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Here's my ReactJS code:

```
import React from 'react';

class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            file: null,
            brand: null
        };

        this.handleFile = this.handleFile.bind(this);
        this.handleBrand = this.handleBrand.bind(this);
        this.handleUpload = this.handleUpload.bind(this);
    }

    handleBrand(e) {
        let brand = e.target.value
        this.setState({brand: brand});
      }

    handleFile(e){

        let file = e.target.files

        this.setState({file: file})
        console.log(file)

    }

    handleUpload(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', this.state.file);
        console.log(this.state.file)

        fetch('http://localhost:5000/upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data,
        })

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleUpload}>
                <div>
                    <input onChange={this.handleFile} id="fileToUpload" type="file" name="filesToUpload" id="filesToUpload"/>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleBrand}>
                    <option value="">- Please select -</option>
                        <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
                        <option value="quick_lanes">Quick Lanes</option>
                        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                        <option value="alfa_romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <br />
                <div>
                    <button>Upload</button>
                </div>

            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

And here's my Flask code:

```
from flask import *
from flask_cors import *
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = "C:/projects/poi_dealers/files"
app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route("/upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_image():

    if request.method == "POST":

        if request.files:

            filesToUpload = request.files["file"]

            filesToUpload.save(os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], filesToUpload.filename))

            print(filesToUpload)

            return redirect(request.url)


    return "All ok"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", use_reloader=False)
```

Here's the thing, i found this code in the web and it works ! I can't understand why, i already read it from top to bottom and i can't see the differences, i don't want to use this code i want to understand what's happening, any suggestions? Here the code i found:

```
import React from 'react';

class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            imageURL: '',
        };

        this.handleUploadImage = this.handleUploadImage.bind(this);
    }

    handleUploadImage(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', this.uploadInput.files[0]);
        data.append('filename', this.fileName.value);

        fetch('http://localhost:5000/upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data,
        }).then((response) => {
            response.json().then((body) => {
                this.setState({ imageURL: `http://localhost:5000/${body.file}` });
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleUploadImage}>
                <div>
                    <input ref={(ref) => { this.uploadInput = ref; }} type="file" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input ref={(ref) => { this.fileName = ref; }} type="text" placeholder="Enter the desired name of file" />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                    <button>Upload</button>
                </div>
                <img src={this.state.imageURL} alt="img" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

And this the output in the python terminal (Of course, it saves the file correctly, 'competitive_process.py' is the name of the file im using for testing purposes):

```
<FileStorage: 'competitive_process.py' ('text/plain')>
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2020 18:39:09] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2020 18:39:09] "GET /upload HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

PS: No CORS errors fortunately, i triple checked that

Regards !

Comment: The other code at least also adds a `filename` to `data`.

Comment: Thank you, i think that its just an uncontrolled component that is just used to name the file, actually that functional code works without that component.

Comment: @DiegoDuarte  What is the contentType of the request ?  is it 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'?

Comment: @BrianPatterson will be files with the extensions: xls, xlsx, csv, txt; so i suppose that the Content Type would be: "application/vnd.ms-excel" and "text/html"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere that you are creating the ref for your file input in the constructor.

Do you have this in a constructor somewhere ?

```
this.uploadInput = React.createRef();
```

Also, where are you declaring/initializing `this.uploadInput`?   Am I missing that somewhere?

Comment: Thank you Brian, unfortunately did not work, even i tried with different Content-Type headers and same issue.

Comment: @DiegoDuarte Updated answer, can you try it that way ?

Comment: Thanks again, the think is, with uncontrolled components works perfectly, but with controlled ones (like my code) ti does not.

Comment: @DiegoDuarte In React, an <input type="file" /> is always an uncontrolled component because its value can only be set by a user, and not programmatically. (https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

Comment: @DiegoDuarte Updated answer,  are you creating that ref somewhere?  I don't see it, but then again, I haven't had my morning coffee yet lol.

Comment: That ref is because is an uncontrolled component, i want to work with controlled ones, that's the code i can't get to run properly.

Comment: @DiegoDuarte Please see previous comment about how file input cannot be controlled with link to reactjs docs where it explains it.